# Can Visual Studio tell me the SSE2 register spill count of compiled code?

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, compiler-construction, sse2

I do not have any real compiler knowledge, and I used to hand-code SSE2 functions for selected pieces of code. I know how to read the generated machine code, but largely unaware of the crazy optimizations made possible by compilers. All of my work is done using Visual Studio.

Is there a way for Visual Studio to tell me the SSE2 register spill count of a piece of function? The reason is that we are soon able to mass-produce SSE2-like code (templated), and we would like each one of them to be compiled into decent quality machine code. We possibly can't manually check each one of them. What I hope to get is some sort of guarantee that the compiled code is acceptable and concise. I don't need to get the last bit of juice.

Alternatively, is there a keyword that works like `__forceinline` that forces compiler to not spill any SSE2 registers, like "__forcenospill" ? (If spill has to happen, the compile will fail, and therefore I would be aware of the problem and try to refactor my SSE2 code.)

Using an existing vector-library or blitter would be out of question because some of the calculations need to be highly registerized (6 or more operands in one step in a "simple operation" (Note #1); intermediate values promoted to 16-bit or 32-bit on-the-fly and converted back, etc) Rephrasing it with a generic vector-library would mean doubling or tripling of runtime (been there, done that).

Commercial tools are okay too, I can certainly afford it given the project's nature.

If there is no such tool, I will resort to profiling. You may downvote this post to let me know that such things don't exist.

Thanks!

(Note #1) it's an adaptive thresholding algorithm.

Comment: Why are you focussing specifically on register spill ? It's just one of many issues to look at when optimising and it's not such a big deal on modern x86 CPUs as it was in Olden Times. Let the compiler take care of register allocation, scoreboarding, etc, and concentrate on writing efficient code. Also use a decent compiler if you can, e.g. ICC - it generates much better SSE code than MSVC.

Comment: @Paul R: I don't have choice on compiler.

Comment: I'm hoping to use that information to help me write better code. E.g. If I know how to write the same function in 5 different ways, then I can choose one that minimize register spill. (Ultimately I should base my choice on profiling, but profiling is subject to other factors that I wish I can isolate those factors one-by-one, register spill being one of them)

Comment: Is SSE2 register spill nearly as fast as register no-spill? Some of the operands are constants; does MSVC optimize them that way? If so, I may say okay and close this question.

Comment: In theory you should be able to get the same throughput when accessing values in L1 cache as when accessing registers - there will be some additional latency but this can often be hidden with good scheduling. Use x86-64 if you can - this doubles the number of available SSE registers. Also if you're stuck with MSVC then this will probably be one of your biggest limiting factors on performance.

Comment: @Paul R: Thanks for your valuable insight. Does Core i7-920 support register-renaming of SSE registers in x86-32 mode?

Comment: I *think* so, but Intel provides very little detailed documentation on their micro-architecture.

Comment: I believe it does support SSE renaming. One the SandyBridge new features is a referenced register file, rather than inlined values in the reservation station. It wouldn't have done the inlining in the first place, if it could have just kept a reference to the fixed SSE register. It must have made the local copy in order to free up the register reference slot and prevent unncessary stalls.  Also, I believe that the L1 latency is in the order of 4 clock cycles - not too much to worry about, unless you have tight dependency chains.

Comment: @rwong I'm pretty sure they renamed SSE registers since the Pentium III. I've measured plenty of SSE loops and the throughput is usually so good that I'm not sure how to explain how it achieved so much throughput other than drastically out of order execution. I wouldn't worry about SSE latencies.

Comment: If your data fits in the cache, it's possible for tuning SSE to improve performance. As soon as you go past what your cache can hold, you will be entirely memory-bound and SSE performance will be effectively irrelevant.

Comment: You might wish to explore Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) which can significantly improve bits of code, and especially help with register allocation.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/xct6db7f(v=vs.80).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/04/04/how-to-build-faster-and-high-performing-native-applications-using-pgo.aspx

Comment: At the point you're worrying about spills on SIMD registers and wanting to start forcing the compiler to avoid spills, that's probably when it's time to grab the assembler. Wanting to take control over register allocation kind of defeats a lot of the purpose of the compiler. In any case, an assembly mindset here can be helpful -- you can then start understanding what registers are used for what based on the assembly output, if only to better tune your C++ code.